# Can iptables state miss some packets?

Tags: iptables, postfix, firewall, email-server, tcp

I tried to setup the iptable rules for MTA. As this MTA is meant only for receiving the emails I allowed INPUT packets from any to destination port 25 with state either new or established, and allowed only output packets with state established from source port 25. Instead of rejecting the packets I logged the ones which would have got rejected. I observed in the logs that some genuine packets could have gotten blocked. These packets were actually the last packets of the transfers (i.e. one with ACK PSH FIN flags set up).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

These might be packets when the state was already removed, like with duplicate FIN packets or packets arriving after the state was removed due to inactivity. Or there might have been never be a state at all and this is just some kind of port scanning (TCP FIN scan - see https://nmap.org/book/scan-methods-null-fin-xmas-scan.html)

Comment: I checked these were genuine packets (i.e. not scanning ones), is there any time for state expiration for iptable because these packets were not too much delayed either (approximately 30 seconds from the last packet) categorized allowed by iptable).

Comment: @AyushGupta: There is a time for state expiration and it can also be configured - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685823/limit-the-duration-of-a-tcp-connection-with-iptables. But in general: you provide only a spotty observation which means one can only speculate what the real issue might be and has no way to verify this speculation.